# How to capture CPU and memory usage in jmeter without port number

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

How to capture CPU and memory usage in jmeter without port number

```
I checked with jp@gc – PerfMon Metrics Collector under Listeners
```

but that required Host and port number
now I have only host but not having port number
i checked that return me an error

```
Response code:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
```

Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connect to *********** failed: Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [ServerAgent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent) application on the system you would like to monitor.

Then you need to launch it. By default the ServerAgent is listening on port 4444 for incoming TCP and UDP requests from the `PerfMon Metrics Collector` listener.

So you will need to set the host to the IP address or DNS hostname of the system you would like to monitor and the port to 4444 (make sure it's open in the [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)))

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)

There is also [SSHMon Samples Collector](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon) listener which doesn't require installation of any software on the system under test side, however it needs SSH server to be up and running there (it's pretty much common on Linux/Unix systems and can be enabled on Windows as well)

Comment: i dont want to use PerfMon Metrics Collector listener. please share any other ways , PerfMon Metrics Collector listener. not working properly in my plan